# Logging into Facebook using Opera keeps reloading, sometimes stuck on the permissions page

Tags: facebook, authentication, opera

I have been building an app using the php sdk for Facebook. The app works perfectly in chrome and Firefox, but when I try in Opera, basically when trying to log in to Facebook the page just reloads.

On occassions I can log in to Facebook, but when click allow to permissions the page doesn't do anything. I have the browser.js enabled but wanted to find out if this was a common problem and if there were any work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook connect JS library contains some pseudo-browser-detection that can cause problems. Opera actually tries to work around some of said problems in browser.js - have you tested with browser.js disabled too? The workaround itself might cause problems..